# Get only numbers, not wrapped specific characters like [[ ]]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sting `"123+[[value_666]]"`, `"123-[[value_666]]"`, `"123*[[value_666]]"`, `"123/[[value_666]]"`
this my regex `/[^0-9%^*/()\-+.]/g`
it takes "123+666", "123-666" etc.
the result should be "123+", "123-" etc

Comment: Remove the wrapped values and keep what's left?

Comment: Maybe you want to remove all inside `[[...]]`? `s.replace(/\[\[.*?]]/g, '')`?

Comment: You say "only numbers", but you expect `123+`, `123-`, etc. that contain symbols, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , symbols are inputs in my case, your regex works for first time, "123+", but not work for "123+666"

Comment: Try `s.match(/^\d+[*+\/-]?/)`, this in line with KiraLT's third solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `[[...]]` pattern from string using [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const values = ["123+[[value_666]]", "123-[[value_666]]", "123*[[value_666]]", "123/[[value_666]]"]
const result = values.map(v => v.replace(/\[\[.*\]\]/, ''))
console.log(result)
```

Or you can match number at the start of the string + one more symbol:

```js
const values = ["123+[[value_666]]", "123-[[value_666]]", "123*[[value_666]]", "123/[[value_666]]"]
const result = values.map(v => v.match(/^(\d+.)/)?.[1])
console.log(result)
```

You can also specify exact symbols to match after the number:

```js
const values = ["123+[[value_666]]", "123-[[value_666]]", "123*[[value_666]]", "123/[[value_666]]"]
const result = values.map(v => v.match(/^(\d+[+-/()*])/)?.[1])
console.log(result)
```

Or you can match everything except `[` symbol:

```js
const values = ["123+[[value_666]]", "123-[[value_666]]", "123*[[value_666]]", "123/[[value_666]]"]
const result = values.map(v => v.match(/^(\d+[^\[])/)?.[1])
console.log(result)
```